# You don't know JS book - Soft Binding

Tags: javascript

I'm currently reading [You don't know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/README.md#you-dont-know-js-this--object-prototypes). In it, there is a section that talks about [soft binding](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md#softening-binding) technique. Basically it's a variation of binding a function to a particular scope/context.

From the book:

> It would be nice if there was a way to provide a different default for default binding (not global or undefined), while still leaving the function able to be manually this bound via implicit binding or explicit binding techniques.

```
if (!Function.prototype.softBind) {
    Function.prototype.softBind = function(obj) {
        var fn = this,
            curried = [].slice.call( arguments, 1 ),
            bound = function bound() {
                return fn.apply(
                    (!this ||
                        (typeof window !== "undefined" &&
                            this === window) ||
                        (typeof global !== "undefined" &&
                            this === global)
                    ) ? obj : this,
                    curried.concat.apply( curried, arguments )
                );
            };
        bound.prototype = Object.create( fn.prototype );
        return bound;
    };
}
```

Generally I understand what the function does except this part:

```
bound.prototype = Object.create( fn.prototype );
```

Why do we have to setup a prototype when using this "soft bind" technique?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why do we have to setup a prototype when using this "soft bind" technique?

It's more for completeness sake than anything else. If someone tries to create a `new` instance of the soft-bound function, they'd expect the resulting object to `[[Prototype]]` link to the same object as the original function's `.prototype` pointed. So, we make sure to set `bound.prototype` equal to reference that same object.

The chances of someone wanting to call `new` on a soft-bound function are low, I'd think, but just to be more safe, it's included nonetheless. The same, btw, is true of the polyfill for the built in `bind(..)` as listed here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Polyfill

Comment: Hi I don't know ` curried = [].slice.call( arguments, 1 )`,`[].slice`return a new array,but call method only eligible for function,not for array.Why this happens?@Kyle Simpson

Answer (score 0):

From [that](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md#softening-binding) page:

> Why is new being able to override hard binding useful?
>
> The primary reason for this behavior is to create a function (that can
>   be used with new for constructing objects) that essentially ignores
>   the this hard binding but which presets some or all of the function's
>   arguments. One of the capabilities of bind(..) is that any arguments
>   passed after the first this binding argument are defaulted as standard
>   arguments to the underlying function (technically called "partial
>   application", which is a subset of "currying").

I guess for the softbind to have the same benefits (to provide a constructor that has default arguments passed to it) you have to set the prototype as well or you're missing prototype functions when you use the bound function as a constructor:

```
//softBind code removed

function Test(arg1,arg2){
    this.arg1=arg1;
    this.arg2=arg2;
}
Test.prototype.sayArgs=function(){
  console.log('args:',this.arg1,this.arg2);
}
//the binding part doesn't do anything so can pass null
var BoundTest = Test.softBind(null, 'arg1');
var bt = new BoundTest('arg2');
bt.sayArgs();//=args:arg1 arg2
```

If you are going to use it this way though you don't have to add softBind to the Function.prototype, you can use normal bind, either native or the MDN polyfill.

Note that with the polyfill you cannot pass a falsy argument as the first parameter to bind or it'll break.

```
//Using the MDN bind polyfill you can't pass any falsy
// value like null, undefined,"",0 and false
var BoundTest = Test.bind({}, 'arg1');
var bt = new BoundTest('arg2');
bt.sayArgs();//=args:arg1 arg2;
```

In the article, the example given is actually broken:

```
var bar = foo.bind( null, "p1" );
var baz = new bar( "p2" );
```

Should be:

```
var bar = foo.bind('anything non falsy' , "p1" );
```

**[update]**

```
//removed if, so it'll set softbind every time
    Function.prototype.softBind = function(obj) {
        var fn = this,
            curried = [].slice.call( arguments, 1 ),
            bound = function bound() {
                return fn.apply(
                    (!this ||
                        (typeof window !== "undefined" &&
                            this === window) ||
                        (typeof global !== "undefined" &&
                            this === global)
                    ) ? obj : this,
                    curried.concat.apply( curried, arguments )
                );
            };
        bound.prototype = Object.create( fn.prototype );
        return bound;
    };

function Test(){
  //this has the right prototype and has
  // the default arguments
  console.log('this is:', this,'arguments',arguments);
  this.name='test';
}
Test.prototype.something=22

var BoundTest = Test.softBind(null,'arg1','arg2');

var bt = new BoundTest();
//bt is same as new Test('arg1','arg2') would be
console.log('bt is:',bt);
//this.name did not affect window
console.log(window.name);//not test 
console.log(bt instanceof Test);//true
```

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy With a falsy passed to hard bind any `this.something=..` will add something to window as well. Not sure what you would specify as 'not work' I've updated the answer with code using soft bind and it does what I would expect it to do. Feel free to modify the code in the answer to show me how to break it.